# get json response from server into variables in jquery ajax on call done()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i want to get json response from server on button click and parse to div, but i stuck how to do it.

```
<button type="submit" id="btPay" name="btPay"> Go for Payment </button><br>
<div id="notif"></div>
```

My external js as follow:

```
  var resJson;
  async function myFunction() {
    var settings = {
      "url": "urlApi",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      "headers": {"headerContents"},
      "data": JSON.stringify({"inputData"})
    };
    
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      resJson = $.parseJSON(response);
    });
  }

  async function setResponse() {
    $("#notif").html(resJson);
  }

  $('#btPay').bind('click', function() {
    myFunction();    
    setResponse();
  })
```

The problem is i cannot get Json response value. based my js, do i missed something?

Thanks and appreciate for help.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Simply sending data as JSON and setting request headers for JSON does not mean you will get a JSON response - it is the server that constructs and sends the JSON response but you have only shown client side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler for the button click you call the functions `myFunction()` and `setResponse()` directly one after the other. The second function will be called before the first will have received the results from the AJAX call. To make it work the `setResponse()` function needs to be called from within the `done()` callback function in your AJAX call in `myFunction()`:

```js
// var resJson;
  function myFunction() {
var settings = { // simplified AJAX call to turn this into a workable snippet
  "url": "https://dummyjson.com/users/13",
  "method": "GET"
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  // `response` contains already a JavaScript object,
  // parsing it again will not work. 
  // Instead I convert it back into a JSON string:
  let resJson = JSON.stringify(response);
  setResponse(resJson);
});
  }

  function setResponse(html) {
    $("#notif").html(html);
  }

  $('#btPay').bind('click', function() {
    myFunction();    
    // setResponse();
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="btPay">get the data</button>
<div id="notif"></div>
```

Another change I made is that  I stopped using the global variable `respJson`. The JSON string is stored in a local variable of the same name and used as the first parameter in the function call `setResponse(respJson)`.

Since the deferred jQuery function `$.ajax()` has not been called with the `await` keyword (but is resolved in a `done()` callback instead) there is no need for the surrounding function to be an asynchronous one and the `async` keyword can be safely dropped.

Comment: Thank you, it's works like what i expected :)

Answer (score 0):

when try in postman with data:

```js
json.stringfy ({
  "external_id": "invoice-{{$timestamp}}",
  "amount": 1800000,
  "payer_email": "customer@domain.com",
  "description": "Invoice Demo #123",
  "payment_methods": [
    "CREDIT_CARD"
  ]
)
```

The response I get like follow:

```
{
  "id": "658xxx",
  "external_id": "invoice-1703409000",
  "user_id": "599xxx",
  "status": "PENDING",
  "merchant_name": "Test Cashpay",
  "merchant_profile_picture_url": "https://url",
  "amount": 1800000,
  "payer_email": "customer@domain.com",
  "description": "Invoice Demo #123",
  "expiry_date": "2023-12-25T09:10:00.915Z",
  "invoice_url": "https://url",
  "available_banks": [],
  "available_retail_outlets": [],
  "available_ewallets": [],
  "available_qr_codes": [],
  "available_direct_debits": [],
  "available_paylaters": [],
  "should_exclude_credit_card": false,
  "should_send_email": false,
  "created": "2023-12-24T09:10:01.030Z",
  "updated": "2023-12-24T09:10:01.030Z",
  "currency": "USD"
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer! If you have more information to add, edit your original question, don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is better to use await to get the answer to get the answer!
just like this:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  resJson = await $.parseJSON(response);
});
async function setResponse() {
 await $("#notif").html(resJson);
}
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: with your code i've got message --> only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.